# How to perform traceroute through a local socks5 proxy?

Tags: internet

Without resorting to iptables /nftables or a proxifier, does traceroute (or similar tool) support options for using a local port for a sock5 proxy?

Here's an example of what I can do with curl. I thought I might be able to do the same with traceroute, but I didn't find such an option in the man page.

```
curl -sS --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 7 -x socks5://127.0.0.1:1234 mysite.com
```

In this case, curl is downloading the page at mysite.com via a socks5 proxy running at my local port 1234. Again, my reason for asking this question is, "Can I do the same with **traceroute**?"

Edit: as per Stephen Harris's comment, it cannot be done.

Comment: traceroute works by sending packets with short TTL values and seeing what router responds back with "time exceeded" errors.  You don't get to control the packet TTL when using a proxy 'cos the connection to the remote source is controlled by the proxy server.  Thus traceroute can not work via proxies.

Comment: @StephenHarris when i run `proxychains traceroute google.com` I get different results that when using `traceroute google.com`

Comment: @MountainX  with the tool `proxychains` you can proxy a lot of programs.